# How can I overload a read for a deferred entity in Entity Framework 6?

Tags: entity-framework, overloading, expression-trees, deferred-execution

Given the following code:

```
var time = ctx.Time.First();
var notes = time.Notes.ToList();
```

This will actually run 2 queries against the database.

Basically, I need to tap into the expression tree and do some custom checking to not return records where the deleted flag is set.

I can do this in the first call by deriving my own class from IDbSet and using

```
Expression IQueryable.Expression
{
    ... Add custom expression here
}
```

However, I don't know how to do override the expression tree in the 2nd call.

Any advice?

Comment: Why not simply use `Where(x => !x.IsDeleted)`?

Comment: Did you try to create a method that accepts a lambda to have that specified by default so that you don't have to bother with the expression tree?

Comment: @haim770: It's a design decision made by the lead dev that we don't want the average dev to have to worry about remembering to include that.

Comment: @Husein Roncevic: Where would I place that method?  In the derived IDbSet class?

Comment: Let me write it as an answer.

Comment: Look at [EntityFramework.DynamicFilters](https://github.com/jcachat/EntityFramework.DynamicFilters).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a repository, let's say ISomeRepository defined as:

```
public interface ISomeRepository
{
    SomeDataModel Get(Func<SomeDataModel, bool> predicate);
}
```

and you implement a class that implements this interface:

```
public class SomeRepository : ISomeRepository
{
    public SomeDataModel Get(Func<SomeDataModel, bool> predicate)
    {
        return someDbSet.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
    }
}
```

When you call this method from somewhere else you would specify:

```
_someRepo.Get(p => p.SomeId == someId && !p.Deleted);
```

That way you don't have to bother with Expression.

Comment: This would not work for accessing `time.Notes` navigation-property.

Comment: Can you process the notes when the information is returned? I know this is not the best approach because there could be a lot of notes. Another approach would be to say: time.Notes.Where(p => !p.Deleted).ToList().

Comment: The real problem is that `IQueryable` navigation properties are not supported and that means EF is always fetching the entire related data (all `Notes` of that `time` entity).

Comment: So which one contains Deleted? Time or Notes?

Comment: @HuseinRoncevic: They both do.  We don't want to actually delete anything in our database, so we need to have a flag on each of our records.  The lead dev wants this to be invisible to the average developer, thus overloading the DbSet and adding in our own IsDeleted == false.

Comment: In that case First has an overload that accepts lambda, so use First(p => !p.Deleted) and use the same thing in Notes.Where(p => !p.Deleted). However, you might have a problem if Time does not return anything. It will throw an exception. FirstOrDefault could be a better option and then check if it is null before a call to Notes.